# Apache POI (poi-ooxml) for Excel 2007 and Spring MVC DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be found

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, maven, apache-poi

I'm having some trouble trying to include Apache POI poi-ooxml library to my project. I'm using Maven and the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

But after doing this I'm not able to start my Spring MVC app again, Here is the stacktrace:

> Exception created : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be found

So, what I understand is that poi-ooxml is including another xml parser that override the default Java VM defaut one that is used by Spring to read its xml configuration file.

If I exclude the 2 following libs:

- xmlbeans
- xml-apis

All is working fine (I'm able to start my Spring app) but of course Apache POI is no longer working as he's missing these 2 required libs...

Any advice will be greatly appreciated ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similiar problem after adding poi-ooxml to my existing groovy application. I've added xercesImpl to project, and it seems to be working. Maybe you should give it a try.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>xerces</groupId>
   <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```